# Passing parameters to inclusion in Liquid templates

Tags: jekyll, liquid

On my Jekyll-powered website I have an inclusion that does something function-like, but I can't figure out how to pass it parameters correctly.

When I use `{% include ... %}`, passing parameters like this..

```
{% include function.liquid foo="{{ baz.quux }}" %}
```

..it just passes the literal string `{{ baz.quux }}` which is, of course, not what I wanted! I want to pass the value of `baz.quux`. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this. I have tested both approaches against the github-pages version of Jekyll.

### Using Capture

Assuming you are referencing `{{ foo }}` in the code of your include, you need to assign a value to foo before calling the include.

Such as:

```
{% capture foo %}{{ baz.quux }}{% endcapture %}
{% include function.liquid %}
```

### Using parameters to Include

This allows you to control the scope of the variable, which it looks like you want. There is some detail of how to set this up in [the templates documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/).

You were nearly right with the syntax, in the template you would use:

```
{% include function.liquid foo=baz.quux %}
```

The part that was missing is that the variable needs to be referenced differently in the code of the include file, you need to use `{{ include.foo }}`

### In Shopify Liquid

As of 2021, you can do the following:

```
{% include 'snippet-file' with bar, foo: baz, foo2: baz2 %}
```

and in the snippet file, retrieve *bar* with `{{ snippet-file }}` and *baz* with `{{ foo }}`.

For Liquid statements, just use the variable name without `{{ }}`, example:

```
{% if snippet-file==0 and foo2==':)' %}
```

Note that it won't work as `include.foo2` like it was shown in the previous section.

Also note that `include` is deprecated, and for new development you should use `render` in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Nick I have done a bit more research and updated my answer. The include syntax with parameters is possible after all.

Comment: Any ideas on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737362/jekyll-shared-template-different-parameters :: I am having a similar issue :(

Comment: That second syntax is brilliant. I can't see it in the docs anywhere, but it works!

Comment: Is there a way to pass HTML in `include` other than plain text or variable? I tried with capture to pass HTML content but it was rendered as text.

Comment: @RamPatra probably best writing up your own question with more detail on what exactly you are trying/have tried

Comment: @DavidHutchison here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60214609/1385441 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Argument error in tag 'include' - Illegal template name

Answer (score 9):

Alongside David Hutchison's, there is a third solution:

## Using [assign](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/#assign)

```
{% assign foo = baz.quux %}
{% include function.liquid %}
```

Now you can reference `{{ foo }}` in your included file.

Comment: This is clearly the preferred way. Might not have been available when the question was asked 6 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Enter the variable without quotes or parentheses, like that:

```
{% include footer.html param="value" variable-param=page.variable %}
```

In your case:

```
{% include function.liquid foo=baz.quux %}
```

It works in my site.

From: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3577#issue-61988857

Answer (score 3):

As September 1rst of 2020, it did worked this way:

`jekyll v4.1.1`

```
{% assign title = 'this is my tittle' %}
{% include subscribeBtn.html title = title %}
```

Then in the Template:

```
<h3>{{ title }}</h3>
```